# Asynctask crashes when user changes fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I found many questions like this but none of them have my case, I found what causes the problem but I cannot find a solution for it, our application has an Asynctask that downloads images of a list like the following:

```
 private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }


    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {
         if(!isCancelled()) {
        InputStream iStream=null;
        String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("flag_path");
        int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");


        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(imgUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
             urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             if(!isCancelled())
             {
                // Connecting to url
                urlConnection.connect();
                //urlConnection.getOutputStream().flush();
                // Reading data from url
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                // Getting Caching directory
                File cacheDirectory = mContext.getCacheDir();

                // Temporary file to store the downloaded image
                File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+position+".png");

                // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(iStream, 8 * 1024);
                // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);

                // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);

                // Flush the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.flush();

                //Close the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.close();

                // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position in the listview
                HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                // Storing the path to the temporary image file
                hmBitmap.put("flag",tmpFile.getPath());

                // Storing the position of the image in the listview
                hmBitmap.put("position",position);

                // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and position
                return hmBitmap;
             }
             return null;

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         }
        return null;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

It will crash when user changes the fragment because of the row `urlConnection.connect();` if I comment it (and the code that depend on it) the asynctask will not crash.

I tried many thing to solve it but nothing works for me I tried to check if the task is canceled I also use the following code to cancel the asyncTask when fragment destroyed:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

         urlConnection.disconnect();

         if(imageLoaderTask != null && imageLoaderTask.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING) {
             imageLoaderTask.cancel(true);
         }




    super.onDestroy();

}
```

Here is my LogCat:

```
    07-23 23:05:48.930: D/AbsListView(15157): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
    07-23 23:05:48.930: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:05:50.035: D/AbsListView(15157): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
    07-23 23:05:50.035: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:05:53.150: D/AbsListView(15157): onDetachedFromWindow
    07-23 23:05:53.225: D/AbsListView(15157): Get MotionRecognitionManager
    07-23 23:05:53.235: D/ProgressBar(15157): setProgress = 0
    07-23 23:05:53.235: D/ProgressBar(15157): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
    07-23 23:05:53.235: D/ProgressBar(15157): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
    07-23 23:05:53.255: D/ProgressBar(15157): setProgress = 0
    07-23 23:05:53.255: D/ProgressBar(15157): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
    07-23 23:05:53.260: D/ProgressBar(15157): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
    07-23 23:05:53.395: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:05:53.495: D/ProgressBar(15157): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
    07-23 23:05:53.495: D/ProgressBar(15157): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
    07-23 23:05:53.495: D/ProgressBar(15157): updateDrawableBounds: right = 96
    07-23 23:05:53.495: D/ProgressBar(15157): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 96
    07-23 23:05:53.590: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:05:53.595: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:05:53.595: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:05:54.005: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:05:54.020: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:05:54.020: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:05:54.030: E/ViewRootImpl(15157): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
    07-23 23:05:54.390: D/ProgressBar(15157): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
    07-23 23:05:54.390: D/ProgressBar(15157): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
    07-23 23:05:54.390: D/ProgressBar(15157): updateDrawableBounds: right = 96
    07-23 23:05:54.390: D/ProgressBar(15157): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 96
    07-23 23:05:54.395: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:05:55.020: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:05:55.500: D/AbsListView(15157): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
    07-23 23:05:55.500: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:05:55.660: D/dalvikvm(15157): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3700K, 27% free 16424K/22420K, paused 15ms, total 16ms
    07-23 23:05:55.710: D/AbsListView(15157): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
    07-23 23:05:55.710: I/MotionRecognitionManager(15157):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0,  
    07-23 23:05:55.710: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:05:55.725: D/AbsListView(15157): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
    07-23 23:05:55.725: I/MotionRecognitionManager(15157):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0,  
    07-23 23:05:55.725: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:05:55.905: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:05:56.535: D/dalvikvm(15157): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2002K, 27% free 16436K/22420K, paused 15ms, total 19ms
    07-23 23:05:56.570: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:05:56.735: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:05:56.795: D/AbsListView(15157): onDetachedFromWindow
    07-23 23:05:56.840: D/AbsListView(15157): Get MotionRecognitionManager
    07-23 23:05:56.925: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:05:57.095: D/AbsListView(15157): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
    07-23 23:05:57.095: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:05:58.530: D/dalvikvm(15157): threadid=11: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
    07-23 23:06:03.415: W/dalvikvm(15157): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41930700)
    07-23 23:06:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15157): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    07-23 23:06:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15157): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    07-23 23:06:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15157):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    07-23 23:06:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15157):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
    07-23 23:06:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15157):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
    07-23 23:06:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15157):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
    07-23 23:06:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15157):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    07-23 23:06:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15157):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    07-23 23:06:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15157):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    07-23 23:06:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15157):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    07-23 23:06:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15157): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-23 23:06:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15157):    at com.Terabyte.myApp.OrganizationFragment$ListViewLoaderTask.doInBackground(OrganizationFragment.java:521)
    07-23 23:06:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15157):    at com.Terabyte.myApp.OrganizationFragment$ListViewLoaderTask.doInBackground(OrganizationFragment.java:1)
    07-23 23:06:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15157):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    07-23 23:06:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15157):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    07-23 23:06:03.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15157):    ... 4 more
    07-23 23:06:04.550: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:06:04.550: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:06:04.555: D/AbsListView(15157): unregisterIRListener() is called 
    07-23 23:06:04.600: D/AbsListView(15157): onDetachedFromWindow
    07-23 23:06:04.620: D/AbsListView(15157): onDetachedFromWindow
    07-23 23:06:04.675: D/AbsListView(15157): onDetachedFromWindow
```

Comment: provide stacktrace from logcat please

Comment: Question updated with LogCat involved.

Comment: Logcat says that you have crash in OrganizationFragment.java at line 521. Can you provide this part of code?

Comment: More specifically, it says there is a NullPointerException on line 521 of that file

Comment: It's OrganizationsXmlParser countryXmlParser = new OrganizationsXmlParser(getActivity().getBaseContext());

Comment: Solved...thanks, the getActivity was null.